# Imagemagick tiling with annotation

Tags: imagemagick, overlay, tiling

I am splitting a big image with:

```
convert input.jpg -crop 2256x3043 +repage +adjoin output-%02d.jpg
```

How can I annotate the tile number at the center of each image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found the solution:

```
convert input.jpg \
        -crop 2256x3043 +repage +adjoin \
        -pointsize 300 -gravity Center -annotate 0 "%[p]" \
        output-%02d.jpg
```

This will split the images in tiles that are 2256x3043 big and write at the center the number of the tile (starting from 0) with a big sized font. I got it using [Imagemagick escape property](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) `%p`, defined as:

> index of image in current image list